# Adding images within the script

Tags: javascript, image

I was wondering if there is any way to add images from within the script. 
For example, the reason I want to do this is so I can add an Image every time the user clicks.
I could add a ton of images in the Body and the hide them all and show them one by one when someone clicks, but it seems like there aught to be a better way.
(In case you didn't get it, I'm **Very** new to JavaScript) :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically add a photo, use code like this:

```
<div id="holder"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';
var holder = document.getElementById('holder');
holder.appendChild(img);
</script>
```

The `Image` object corresponds to the `<img>` element.  To learn more about the `Image` (aka `HTMLImageElement`) object, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement).  To learn more about the `appendChild` method, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by follow these steps:

1. Choose the element in your html that you want to add image to. Example: `<div id='maker'></div>`
2. add an event to your button in your html. Example: `<button onclick='addImg()'>Add</button>`
3. then write these codes to your script tag or your .js file.
   Here is the code:

   ```
   function addImg()
   {
      var maker = document.getElementById('maker');
       var image = document.createElement('img');
       image.src = '/image/path/with/extension.jpg';
       maker.appendChild(image);
   }
   ```